# TypeScript Joi: Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'Root'

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I dont understand why im  getting the error `Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'Root'.ts(2339)` and `Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`
I have imported "@hapi/joi": "^17.0.0" and "@types/hapi__joi": "^16.0.6"

```
import Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { WriteError } from 'mongodb';
import sha1 from 'sha1';
import { user } from '../models/user';

class Home {
  static index = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const schema = Joi.object().keys({
          email: Joi.string()
            .lowercase()
            .trim()
            .max(320)
            .email({ minDomainSegments: 2 })
            .required(),
          fullName: Joi.string()
            .trim()
            .max(70)
            .required(),
          password: Joi.string()
            .trim()
            .min(8)
            .max(70)
            .required(),
        });
        const { email, password, fullName } = req.body;
        Joi.validate({ email, password, fullName }, schema, (err, val) => {
//             ^ Error                                 Error ^     ^ Error   
          if (err) {
            throw new Error('Failed to validate input ' + err.details[0].message);
          }
          req.body = val;
          next();
        });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send({
          code: sha1('validateJoin' + error.message || 'Internal Server Error'),
          error: error.message || 'Internal Server Error',
        });
      }
  };
}

export { Home };
```

Comment: Hi Bill, did you get the solution for this issue??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To Validate, you can use this code below:

```
schema.validateAsync({ email, password, fullName }).then(val => {
      req.body = val;
    }).catch(err => {
      throw new Error('Failed to validate input ' + err.details[0].message);
    })
```

I hope it's work